# How can I get all titles from a lot of tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 categorys for movies and one table for each category. One table called action, one called comedy and one called horror. Each table has 'title' and 'status'.
How can I select all titles from all tables where 'status' is 'new'?

I tried it this way:

```
SELECT
    action.title,
    comedy.title,
    horror.title
FROM
    action,
    comedy,
    horror
WHERE
    action.status = 'new' OR
    comedy.status = 'new' OR
    horror.status = 'new'
```

But I get all titles, even if status isn't new.
I tried a JOIN, but I don't know how to join 3 tables the right way..

Comment: "and one table for each category" <- that's your problem right there. You should only have one table.

Comment: It's just an quick example I came up with. My real design is better and requires more than one table. But thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query each table separately for `new` movie titles and `UNION` them together -

```
SELECT  action.title
FROM    action
WHERE   action.status = 'new'

UNION

SELECT  comedy.title
FROM    comedy
WHERE   comedy.status = 'new'

UNION

SELECT  horror.title
FROM    horror
WHERE   horror.status = 'new'
```

But as Mat said in the comment, your schema seems to be badly designed. You should have only one table for movies, with a different category table and a relation between this category and the movie table.

Answer (score 2):

Try it by using the keyword `UNION`:

```
SELECT action.title
FROM action
WHERE action.status = 'new' 
UNION
SELECT comedy.title
FROM comedy
WHERE comedy.status = 'new' 
UNION
SELECT horror.title
FROM horror
WHERE horror.status = 'new'
```

`UNION` combines several queries with the same count of columns and returns it as one resultset.